# Mat-table display rows depending on condition

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, mat-table

I only want to show data on the table if status == 'done'.
I tried doing but what i did was just remove the status but it is still displaying the row.
How to do this?

data

```
    { 
        equipmentOrdered: 'laptop', 
        qty: 1,
        status: 'processing', 
    },
    { 
        equipmentOrdered: desktop, 
        qty: 2,
        status: 'done', 
    },
    { 
        equipmentOrdered: 'keyboard', 
        qty: 2,
        status: 'processing', 
    },
```

table

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="equipmentOrdered"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Equipment Ordered</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">{{purchaseOrder.equipmentOrdered}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="qty"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>QTY</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">{{purchaseOrder.qty}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      //this is just not displaying the status, how to not include whole row?
      <ng-container matColumnDef="status"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">
            <ng-container *ngIf="purchaseOrder.status !='done' ">
            {{purchaseOrder.status}}
          </ng-container>
          </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it won't conditionally hide it this way, because you are trying to tamper with it inside the `mat-cell` definition, not `mat-row`'s.

I think the best way would be to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the dataSource.

In your `.ts`:

```js
// replace with the variable you pass to your mat-table's [dataSource]
this.dataSource = dataSourceArray.filter(row => row.status === 'done'); // returns array with only status === 'done'
```

**Note:** if your dataSource is not an ordinary array, but a `MatTableDataSource` instance, you should assign your filtered array to **`this.dataSource.data`**, not `this.dataSource`.

Another (a little less elegant, but closer to your original approach) way would be to hide your `mat-row` with the `hidden` attribute:

```html
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
    [hidden]="row.status !== 'done'"></mat-row>
```

Comment: You're welcome! :) Which of the approaches did you end up preferring?

Comment: The first one. i have not tried the second one because i am in a hurry now. i will try later. thanks for the options!

Comment: The `hidden` attribute style gets overwritten with the `display: flex` style on the `mat-row`